# Animate.css change starting position

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

So I'm using bootstrap menu with animate.css (example - https://jsfiddle.net/wpf9whd6/1/ ). The issue is that if I click on the button, the menu starts to load way above the button. The wanted effect would be for it to start to load right under the button, so it would look like, the menu is sliding out under the button.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu slideInDown animated">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the dropdown in an element that has the height of the viewport or just some sort of height that will accommodate the height of the dropdown (a page wrapper or whatever), hide the `overflow-y` so that the starting point of the menu sliding down is hidden, but the bottom isn't. Then use `z-index` to put the button over the dropdown.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-toggle {
  z-index: 1001;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
https://jsfiddle.net/wpf9whd6/#update
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu slideInDown animated">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can simply add styling to `<ul class="dropdown-menu slideInDown animated">` I put in `margin-top` and it moved it, just make it where ever you want to start. here is the line i used `<ul class="dropdown-menu slideInDown animated" style='margin-top:100px !important'>`

Comment: This does not work without moving the menu down, that is - https://jsfiddle.net/wpf9whd6/2/ .

Comment: @VdasDorls that appears to be the animation that is being used, it just appears and then the whole thing slides down, there is no way, using that animation, for it to start below the button and not end up lower